# Getting Intel Wifi Link 5100 to work with Windows 8.1 PC

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, drivers

I have an HP 110-210 desktop with Windows 8.1. The PC did not come with a wireless card, but it has a port for a Half Mini PCIe Card.

I already have a Netgear USB wireless adapter, but I wanted to switch to an internal card so I bought an Intel Wifi Link 5100 that is a half-sized card. I put it in my PC, but Windows doesn't seem to recognize it at all.

It doesn't show up in the Device Manager, so I tried adding it manually. I was able to do this, but then Windows complains that it cannot load the driver for the device. I downloaded drivers from the Intel website, but they didn't help. I installed Intel PROSet Wireless software and ran one of its diagnostic tests, which gives an error that "Wireless Hardware is not bound to transport driver".

I suspect that the problem is caused by either a bad wireless card or a bad port, but I don't know. Any ideas how I could get it to work?

P.S. The card didn't come with a manual, so I'm not sure if I was supposed to take the labels off both sides before installing it, or if I need to hookup antennas, or anything like that.

Comment: Google always knows how to find the manual, did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I Googled for the manual and found the product brief and the Intel wireless software user guide, but unfortunately not a manual for the card itself.

Comment: Since the card wasn't working, I returned it and bought a Panda 300Mbps adapter. I wanted a WiFi adapter that would work on Windows and Linux, and the Panda is awesome because it works plug-and-play with both OSes.